# How to disable Windows 10 Feedback Hub?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Feedback Hub hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> ([Feedback Hub window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTFiD.png) appears) interferes with Windows usage, in particular with games as it is common to accidentally press these keys during gameplay.

I have set "feedback frequency" to "never" in Windows 10 settings > privacy > feedback and diagnostics.

Comment: Simply type Feedback Hub in start --> Right click --> Uninstall

Comment: @Bungicasse: Sorry for not trying uninstalling, I was sure that FH is a system application.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know two different ways that you can get rid of this.

**Option 1: Uninstalling Feedback Hub**

Press the Windows key and search for Feedback Hub --> Right click --> Uninstall

**OR**

Open Settings --> Apps --> Manage optional features --> Scroll down and find Feedback Hub --> Click Uninstall

**Option 2: Using software such as ShutUp10**

Using freeware tools like ShutUp10 will give you complete control over Windows 10. This will not uninstall Feedback Hub but simply disable the shortcut.

Comment: I do not see an option in ShutUp10 for this. Which one is it?